# Java spring MVC - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm making a java spring mvc web app.

My get request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/newAssignment", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView newAssignment(ModelAndView model) throws IOException {
    Assignment newAssignment = new Assignment();
    model.addObject("assignment", newAssignment);
    model.setViewName("upload");
    return model;
}
```

My Form:

```
<form:hidden path="assignmentId"/>
        <tr>
            <td>Title:</td>
            <td><form:input path="title" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Description:</td>
            <td><form:input path="description" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Author:</td>
            <td><form:input path="author" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Level</td>
            <td><form:input path="level" /></td>
        </tr>
                    <tr>
            <td>Region</td>
            <td><form:input path="region" /></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="file" path="path"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Save"></td>
        </tr>
```

My POST request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveAssignment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveAssignment(@ModelAttribute Assignment assignment, HttpSession session) {
    assignmentDAO.saveOrUpdate(assignment, session);        
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
}
```

My Implementation:

```
@Override
public void saveOrUpdate(Assignment assignment, HttpSession session) {
    System.out.println("insert");

    //insert
        String sql = "INSERT INTO `Library`.`Assignments` "
                + "(`title`, `description`, `path`, `level`, `Author`, `region`) "
                + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
        System.out.println(assignment.getTitle());
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql,
                assignment.getTitle(),
                assignment.getDescription(), 
                assignment.getPath(), 
                assignment.getLevel(), 
                assignment.getAuthor(), 
                assignment.getRegion());

}
```

I have a strong feeling that it's because my author should be a User Object, my region should be a region object, my level should be a level object.

How do i do this in the html? og can i do it somewhere else? all this ancient technology gives me is:

```
type Status report

messageBad Request

descriptionThe request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

Comment: Do you get the error from the `GET` endpoint or the `POST` endpoint?

Comment: POST, i can get the page, fill the info, and attempt post,then i get the error

Comment: You should look in your browser dev tools (e.g. Firebug) and find the exact `POST` request that is being sent. Then it should be obvious why it does not match your endpoint.